# Is each Peano continuum a topological fractal?

Tags: gn.general-topology, fractals, continuum-theory

> **Problem.** Is each Peano continuum a topological fractal?

A compact Hausdorff space $X$ is a *topological fractal* if $X=\bigcup_{i=1}^n f_i(X)$ for some continuous maps $f_1,\dots,f_n:X\to X$ such that for any sequence $(g_i)_{i\in\omega}\subset\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}^{\omega}$ the intersection $\bigcap_{m\in\omega} g_0\circ\dots\circ g_m(X)$ is a singleton.

(The problem was posed on 16.11.2014 by Taras Banakh on [page 3](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=0&page=3) of [Volume 0](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=0) of the [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka)).

The prize for solution: *A lunch in "Szkocka".*

Comment: Karasova and Vejnar proved in (https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.15394) that a Peano continuum is a topological fractal if it has uncountably many local cut points.